# Run command on startup (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app

I need to run the command:

sudo apachectl stop

So that my database web server can handle incoming requests instead of the Apple server.  However, this does not survive a restart.  I tried setting up the file KillApache.plist in the /Library/LaunchAgents/ folder.  This is the text:

Label
    KillApache

```
<key>OnDemand</key>
<false/>

<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
        <string>sudo apachectl stop</string>
  </array>
```

However, I got the following messages in the log:

9/1/14 11:12:31.832 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[223]: (KillApache[632]) Job failed to exec(3). Setting up event to tell us when to try again: 2: No such file or directory
9/1/14 11:12:31.832 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[223]: (KillApache[632]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 2

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong or what the best way would be to get this to run at startup before the server takes control?  Thanks.

Randy Kaempen